# Probability $P(A < B)$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Given two independent and continuous random variables $A$ and $B$ with cumulative distributions $F_A$ and $F_B$, show that $$P(A<B) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} F_A(x)\, F'_B(x)\,dx.$$

Is this something obvious and available in text books ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let the density functions be $f_A(x)$ and $f_B(y)$. So the joint density is $f_A(x)f_B(y)$.

To find the probability that $A\lt B$, we integrate the joint density over the part of the plane made up of points $(x,y)$ such that $x\lt y$. 
So we are integrating over the part of the plane above the line $x=y$.

This double integral can be expressed as the iterated integral
$$\int_{y=-\infty}^\infty\left( \int_{x=-\infty}^y f_A(x)\,dx\right) f_B(y)\,dy.$$

The innner integral is $F_A(y)$, and $f_B(y)=F'_B(y)$, so we end up with
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_A(y)F_B'(y)\,dy.$$
What you quoted uses a different name for the dummy variable of integration.

Comment: You are welcome. I think the formula would be better (easier to grasp instantly) if the author had used $F_A f_B$.

Answer (score 2):

In order to show that this is the case, you can begin by writing:
$$
P(A<B)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^bF'_A(a) F'_B(b)\, da\,db 
$$
Writing this as
$$
P(A<B)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\int_{-\infty}^bF'_A(a) \,da\right)F'_B(b)\, db 
$$
We obtain the desired formula.